# PostgreSQL could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-9.5

I'm working fine these past months but yesterday suddenly my PostgreSQL is showing this error in all my applications.

`could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)`

Is the server running on host "IP address" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

And this happens from nothing, I do anything in my database and in my server, I have the server in DigitalOcean and they say that don't touch in anything in my server.

I'm already doing this

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432***  
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

this configuration already is the same when i'm installed my PostgreSQL and working it all these months and one day this error occurs, I don't know what happens.

My version from PostgreSQL is 9.5 and running a Ubuntu on my server.

Comment: Have you changed Image gateway/network settings? It would be great if you state what exactly you're doing?

try to change listen_addresses = '*'

Comment: Then restart postgres with: "service postgresql restart"

Comment: I do nothing A. Chandu.

I'm just working, how I work every day and in one day this error occurs.

I change nothing ins PostgreSQL is strange something like this happens,

listen_addresses = ''*" this configuration is not to accept all IP's address? I already have this configuration set, why I need to change?

What I do is, I'm already used 'service PostgreSQL restart', 'service PostgreSQL stop', 'service PostgreSQL start', nothing happens

Comment: I tried my ip and the port 5432.

https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

and show is closed it is normal? It is closed because PostgreSQL is using it?

Comment: What does `service postgresql status` say? When active then what does `netstat -anp | grep postgres` say? Also your firewall status could be helpful `ufw status verbose`.